# Cakephp and Containable error

Tags: cakephp, containable

I have the containable behavior in my appModel.
When I do this in my Asset model:

```
$this->Asset->contain();
$this->find.....
```

I'm getting the following error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function contain() on a non-object

However, when I use contain like this it works fine:

```
$this->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Asset.name ='=>'goodAsset'), 'contain'=>false) );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check that the model really has the containable behaviour with `debug($this->Asset->actsAs)`.

Comment: no need to call $this->contain(); and set 'contain' => false, they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `$this->Model->method()` only in controllers. In the model drop the model object from between (because `$this` already points to it):

```
$this->contain();
```